# Node server and client on different ports?

Tags: node.js, express, xmlhttprequest, webserver

Below I have code that is run from a single call from my package.json

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 3000;

//raspberryPI
//const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const { ChatClient } = require("dank-twitch-irc");
const { readPin } = require('./JavaScript/readPin');

const keywordsList = [];
*THIS IS A APP.USE FOR CORS, ONLY APPLICABLE IF I CAN GET THEM TO TALK IN THE FIRST PLACE*
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:3000"); // update to match the domain you will make the request from
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname+'/views/index.html'); // change the path to your index.html
});

 app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  //res.sendFile(__dirname+'/views/index.html');  
  // res.writeHead(200, {
  //     'Connection': 'keep-alive',
  //     'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
  //     'Content-Type': 'text/event-stream'
  //   });
  //   res.flushHeaders();
    const arrayToString = JSON.stringify(Object.assign({}, keywordsList))
    const stringToJsonObject = JSON.parse(arrayToString);
   

  res.send("data: " + arrayToString + "\n\n");

  //res.status(500).send({ error: 'something blew up' })
});
//app.use(express.static('views'))
//listen on port 3000
app.listen(port, () => console.info('Listening on port', { port }));
```

*much more code beyond this but only above is applicable*

When I start my application, depending on where I put my static HTML page call (before or after the first GET res) I will get the page up and running on my localhost:3000 but I am unable to connect it the express server OR I just get the output of data that I am pushing to the array "keywordsList" but no HTML page. I get various errors every time in the console that I can display if need be.

Through reading online I have realized I probably don't understand that I cannot serve both the server and the client on the same port AND get them to talk to each other. While that's okay, there aren't many solutions available online on how to fix it.

I was hoping someone could help me understand a few things:
Am I right in assuming that I need to keep my client and server on separate ports in order for them to correctly talk to each other? If so, is there a simple way you can explain that to me here or should I go with my gut instinct and overhaul the essential architecture of my project to completely separate the client from the server (I am only EVER attempting to display an individual HTML page that will just constantly receive random calls from my API so I think it's a bit much).If I am not right, I can go into further explanation of the GET errors I keep getting in the browser but it's usually 404 app.js not found.

Sorry the code is a little confusing and commented randomly. It's pretty bare bones because I have gone back and forth trying to just get a simple HTML page to load data and the server just WON'T connect to the client.

Thank you for any feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Realized what I was doing wrong. I didn't understand that the client needs to be on its own local server (mine is currently set to localhost:3000) and then the actual webserver needs to be on its own port (localhost:8000). Then you need to configure the two to talk to each other through a proxy and probably work around cors.

Anyway that's what I did and I get information to the page now. Just got to figure out how to structure payloads lol